# Как сделать такие же пиксельные логотипы?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

**Привет, я тут увидел вот это**

[image: Логотипы]

Не подскажите, как они могли сделать это?

Comment: Сайт vercel-а, там снизу это

Comment: Уважаемые участники ruSO, пожалуйста, не закрывайте этот вопрос. Занимаюсь...

Comment: Понял, я не буду закрывать

Answer (score 2):

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" width="48" height="48"><path d="M0.3542 0.1458 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3125 0.1875 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3542 0.1875 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3958 0.1875 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2708 0.2292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3125 0.2292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3542 0.2292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3958 0.2292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4375 0.2292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6875 0.2292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2708 0.2708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3125 0.2708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3958 0.2708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4375 0.2708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6458 0.2708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6875 0.2708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.7292 0.2708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2292 0.3125 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2708 0.3125 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4375 0.3125 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4792 0.3125 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6042 0.3125 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6458 0.3125 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6875 0.3125 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.7292 0.3125 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.7708 0.3125 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2292 0.3542 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2708 0.3542 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4375 0.3542 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4792 0.3542 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6042 0.3542 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6458 0.3542 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.7292 0.3542 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.7708 0.3542 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1875 0.3958 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2292 0.3958 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4792 0.3958 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.5208 0.3958 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.5625 0.3958 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6042 0.3958 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.7708 0.3958 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8125 0.3958 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1875 0.4375 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2292 0.4375 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.5208 0.4375 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.5625 0.4375 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.7708 0.4375 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8125 0.4375 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1458 0.4792 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1875 0.4792 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.5208 0.4792 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.5625 0.4792 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8125 0.4792 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8542 0.4792 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1458 0.5208 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1875 0.5208 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.5208 0.5208 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.5625 0.5208 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8125 0.5208 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8542 0.5208 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1042 0.5625 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1458 0.5625 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4792 0.5625 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.5208 0.5625 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8542 0.5625 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8958 0.5625 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.0625 0.6042 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1042 0.6042 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1458 0.6042 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4792 0.6042 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.5208 0.6042 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8542 0.6042 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8958 0.6042 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.9375 0.6042 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.0625 0.6458 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1042 0.6458 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4375 0.6458 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4792 0.6458 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8958 0.6458 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.9375 0.6458 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.0208 0.6875 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.0625 0.6875 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4375 0.6875 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4792 0.6875 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.9375 0.6875 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.9792 0.6875 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.0208 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.0625 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1042 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1458 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1875 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2292 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2708 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3125 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3542 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3958 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.4375 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6458 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6875 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.7292 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.7708 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8125 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8542 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8958 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.9375 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.9792 0.7292 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.0625 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1042 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1458 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.1875 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2292 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.2708 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3125 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3542 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.3958 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6042 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6458 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.6875 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.7292 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.7708 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8125 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8542 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.8958 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 M0.9375 0.7708 m-0.0208,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 0.0416,0 a0.0208,0.0208 0 1,0 -0.0416,0 " fill="var(--ds-gray-1000)">
</path>
<path d="" fill="var(--ds-gray-1000)" opacity="0.5"></path>
</svg>
```

В данном случае - это svg

Comment: Вы можете сами скопировать код понравившегося элемента. Выбираете понравившийся элемент на сайте, нажимаете правой кнопкой мыши на него и выбираете просмотреть код. Откроется инспектор кода. Если видите там svg выше, то выбирайте svg. Слева нажимайте на ... правой кнопкой мыши, копировать - копировать элемент. То, что скопировали, вставляете в редактор и получаете результат

Comment: Далее этот результат анимируете, разукрашиваете и т.д.

Comment: Теперь интересно, как они смогли каждый кружок анимировать. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Devollox, SVG иконка - это статика без ховера, поверх него накладывается Canvas, который либо заранее имеет такие же точки, либо они отрисовываются по SVG (скорее этот вариант), далее уже в Canvas, по какому-то алгоритму шума или рандомно, уже эти точки меняют цвет.

Answer (score 0):

там используется canvas.

> Тег  добавляет растровый холст на страницу. Этот холст можно
> использовать для отрисовки 2D- или 3D-графики, анимаций, видео.

быть может, это просто гифка.

Comment: Даже если гифка, очень интересно как они смогли это сделать. Почему то очень сильно заинтересовало меня это.

Answer (score 0):

Если увеличить эти **svg** элементы, то можно увидеть, что автор создал их из маленьких точек, имитируя при этом подобие пикселей, но круглых.[image]

Предполагаю, что далее автор просто анимировал каждую точку средствами **JavaScript** или фреймворков, путём простого изменения цвета каждой точки с течением времени.

Comment: Да я вижу, но мои скиллы не позволяют это сделать(

Comment: @Devollox если товарищ UModeL сделает, то все вместе у него поучимся, я знаю он сделает красиво и понятно. 

Чисто теоретически: реализовать такое элементарно, если бы каждая точка была отдельным **path**, но как сделать так из одного **path**, тут моих скиллов тоже не хватает пока.